# How to equal images height in bootstrap different two column size

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using two different bootstrap grid columns but images height are not equal in the grid. If i fixed the height images look stretched. Please see below my code:

```
         <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-8 " >
                 <img class="img-responsive" src="images/green.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4" >
                 <img class="img-responsive" src="images/green.jpg">
              </div>
         </div>
```

Below result I'm getting

[image]

how can equal both images height without stretched. Thanks

Comment: It's because of the size of the columns, you may need to use a container with a height and do something like `object-fit: cover;`. Alternatively perhaps use flexbox?

Comment: Hi @AndyHolmes I tried object-fit:cover; on image but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a containing divider for each image which will have a static height and a variable width. You can then use background-image and background-size: cover. Example:

```
.image-container{
 height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

And then for HTML try the following:

```
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8 " >
             <div class="image-container" style="background-image: url('images/green.jpg');">
             </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4" >
             <div class="image-container" style="background-image: url('images/green.jpg');">
             </div>
          </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: You could just use object-fit on the image rather than setting it as a background

Comment: That is an option if you know that your audience will never use EDGE v15 and below. Background-size: cover wont cause any issues with compatibility.

Comment: No problem @Mudassar

Comment: This is not really an answer as you are using background images.

Comment: It doesn't really make much difference, from the view of a user, all they will see is 2  images with the same height. It doesn't matter if its a background image or not. If anything its better because its scales responsively and is also harder for others to steal the image (unless they know about dev tools).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/bjnpz7q7/

```css
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.img-responsive {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure both your cols have the same height.To do so, you can use flex like this:

```
.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:   flex;
}
.col-md-8, col-md-4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

then, remove the Bootstrap class "img-responsive", and apply this css to your img tag like this:

```
.img{
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Check the pen I've created [here](https://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/OjNKBK)

Comment: This was my idea but as another user pointed out, not all browsers support object-fit

Comment: Then you can use Modernizer to detect all the browsers that support object-fit and if not just use jquery to take the src image and add it as a background image.

Answer (score -3):

```
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 " >
             <img class="img-responsive" src="images/green.jpg">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6" >
             <img class="img-responsive" src="images/green.jpg">
          </div>
     </div>
```

Try this this makes your column fixed

Comment: How does this fix the problem? Why are you suggesting to change the column size?

Comment: I want to give more width to one column like one should bigger and 2nd smaller but equal height